# No sure how to create the Todo app using Meteor Framework

Tags: meteor

I tried replicating the todos application without using the example meteor terminal commentlets

Steps, i followed, (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 build)
In terminal - meteor create todos
-- created the todos

a default *.html, *.css, *.js create underneath to the todos folder,
i deleted and replaced the actual todo artifacts into to it (e.g. client, server, public folders to the root) -> tried running the app - UI appears but the functionality breaks

I just wanna know what is ideal way create a app something similar structure as todos app.
This might help other folks to create a larger applications... currently i stuck in single *.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad i found it, just use this commentlet on terminal

> meteor list --using

the above commentlet will list you out all the packages used for the current meteor project

Just add those project to the newly create meteor project and write your own structure, i found another way struture the project which i post as soon as possible...

> meteor list --using
>
> - underscore
> - backbone
> - spiderable
> - accounts-ui
> - accounts-weibo
> - accounts-google
> - accounts-facebook
> - accounts-password
> - accounts-twitter
> - jquery
> - preserve-inputs

intersting fact is todo example comes two version one with secure and non secure packages - out-of-box build release with 0.4.2, and 0.5.0 respectively...

Answer (score 0):

There's also a .meteor directory per project. Did you copy that too?

I've used a vagrant (https://github.com/pixelhandler/vagrant-dev-env) to install all of the dependencies and have an app running fine.

I just used 'meteor create myapp' like the docs say.

Comment: i didn't copy that .meteor hidden directory files, but i've added the dependency packages e.g. backbone, spiderable, jquery, preserve-inputs to the project. via meteor add <<packagename>>

Comment: assume creating a new todo project no by copying files from the example source - instead right thru from scratch...